# Creating a 2d array based on two different arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I receive constant data, for ease of life I get both data values that I receive and put them into each into a different array, the idea of this is so that I can link a value of Variable2 to a value of Variable1.  Now, Variable1 will always be a value between 0 and 7, which I want to use this value to index the other array containing all values from variable2, data is polled serially inside a for loop, so I get data for both variables constantly.
an example of data I get:

```
Variable1:  6 Variable2:  1499.6
Variable1:  6 Variable2:  1186.5
Variable1:  6 Variable2:  570.4
Variable1:  1 Variable2:  405.9
Variable1:  1 Variable2:  754.0
Variable1:  1 Variable2:  197.2
Variable1:  1 Variable2:  726.0
Variable1:  1 Variable2:  959.1
Variable1:  1 Variable2:  709.6
```

An example of two arrays of data for variable1 and variable 2 is below:

```
  Variable2 ={  [1499.6, 1186.5, 570.4, 405.9, 754.0, 197.2, 726.0, 959.1, 709.6]}
  Variable1 ={  [[6], [6], [6], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]}
```

So my question is how would I grab these two arrays and make it so for example if I where to do print(VariableArray[6][2]) results in it printing : 570.4 which is the 3rd variable2 corresponding to Variable1 = 6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with a dictionary of lists:

```
{
    6: [1499.6, 1186.5, 570.4],
    1: [405.9, 754.0, 197.2, 726.0, 959.1, 709.6]
}
```

As an example in the Python REPL:

```
>>> d = {6: [1499.6, 1186.5, 570.4], 1: [405.9, 754.0, 197.2, 726.0, 959.1, 709.6]}
>>> d[6][2]
570.4
```

The idea is:
Keep a key for your `0` to `7` values (initially `Variable1`) and for each of those, store a list of values where you push the new data.

You could initialize this dictionary like so:

```
d = {
    0: [],
    1: [],
    2: [],
    3: [],
    4: [],
    5: [],
    6: [],
    7: [],
}
```

Or you could use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but first, make sure you understand lists and dictionaries.

In order to append data to a list you'd do (assuming `42.0` is your new value and the dictionary already contains the data you posted in the question):

```
d[6].append(42.0)
```

Which yields:

```
{6: [1499.6, 1186.5, 570.4, 42.0], 1: [405.9, 754.0, 197.2, 726.0, 959.1, 709.6]}
```

Or more generally: `d[Variable1].append(Variable2)`.

**Note:** make sure your list will not grow indefinitely.

Please read the general theory and usage on dictionaries and lists in Python here (minimal reading for better understanding):

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: in code how would I do this? I attempted to do a dictionary append, but it would always just keep the last value of each key,  so in my case i would end up with:

{
6:[670.4],
1:[709.6]
}

Comment: Edited the post to include the appending.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that the list will grow a lot,  im building both lists above constantly, after a certain number of datapoints I will clear the list and create 2 new lists after getting the data of the list, I will probably post a questio nif I am unable to find the lowest value for each key since the idea I have is to build around a list of 100 elements, create the dictionary, pick the lowests values per key, to create a new array of 8 elements where the index position is equal to the key of the dictionary , and the values are  the lowest per key. then start again from 0. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's better to post that question separately. Please make sure to click the check mark icon to the left of the answer if it solves the problem posted here.